# How to get value of placeholder in google cloud function with python and firestore trigger?

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

The google cloud docs describe how one can set up the google cloud functions written in python, which are to be triggered by firestore events (e.g. create, write, delete).
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore

The docs also mention the use of wildcards (placeholders) in the document path:

> Wildcards are written in triggers using curly braces, as follows:
> `"projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/collection/{document_wildcard}"`

However, I can't find how to access the *value* of the document_wildcard from within the cloud function. E.g. I can't find it on the `context` variable.

Does someone have a hint? Are the values of wildcards available inside python google cloud functions?

Comment: From looking at the [code samples](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore#code_sample) in the documentation you linked, it seems the code extracts the parameter(s) from manipulating `event.value.name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the wildcards can be found in `data.value.name` - many thanks to Frank van Puffelen for pointing this out.

E.g., the following google cloud function

```
def my_cloud_function(data, context):
    print(data.get("value").get("name"))
    return
```

triggered by *create* events on

```
projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/collection/{document_wildcard}
```

prints the *actual* full path to the created document, e.g.

```
projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/collection/o6NNBsnWfaA9N5iJx7r9
```